# Whats wrong with this code?

Tags: bash

```
#!bin/bash

if [ ! -e $1 ];
then
        echo "error... no such file"
        exit
else
        END=$(wc -l $1 | cut -d" " -f1)
        for (( i=1;i<=END;i++));
        do
        echo -e " $i \n"
        echo "$(head -$i $1 |tail -1)"
        temp=$(head -$i $1 |tail -1|)
        echo "this is temp $temp"

         done

fi
```

The line that fails is me assigning a value to `temp`. I get a `` syntax error near unexpected token `)' `` error but I don't understand why

Comment: You have a | symbol at the end of the tail -l in temp, where you initialize it. Thats probably what its complaining about

Comment: wow.. that took 2 hours

Comment: Haha it happens :)

Comment: Also, that shebang...

Comment: I am surprised that you don't need `$END` in the `for`-loop, but `END` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented earlier, and as everyone else mentioned, your line of code has a syntax error.

```
temp=$(head -$i $1 |tail -1|)
```

This should be:

```
temp=$(head -$i $1 |tail -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a typo, `|)` in:

```
temp=$(head -$i $1 |tail -1|)
```

You need to either remove the pipe (`|`) or feed it to another command.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in line:

```
temp=$(head -$i $1 |tail -1|)
```

You write a trailing pipe `|`.